# angular 7 mat-card in only row using flex layout

Tags: css, angular, mat-card

I work with angular 7 and I use mat-card and flex layout.

I want to place side by side in only row
and the three cards will be centered in the page ( meaning the position of the three card will be in the center )

like this :
[image]

I use this code :

.html

```
  <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" fxLayoutGap="25px">
    <mat-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let member of members" fxFlex="calc(33%-25px)" fxFlex.sm="calc(50%-25px)" >
      <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
        <mat-card-title>{{member.title}}</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>{{member.subtitle}}</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <img mat-card-image [src]="member.url" alt="Photo of {{member.title}}">
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>
          {{member.content}}
        </p>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
```

.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-card-view-demo',
  templateUrl: './card-view-demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card-view-demo.component.scss']
})
export class CardViewDemoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  members: {title: string, subtitle: string, content: string, url: string}[] = [
    {title: 'Title', subtitle: 'Subtitle', content: 'Content here', url: '../../assets/img/app/shiba2.jpg'},
    {title: 'Title', subtitle: 'Subtitle', content: 'Content here', url: '../../assets/img/app/shiba2.jpg'},
    {title: 'Title', subtitle: 'Subtitle', content: 'Content here', url: '../../assets/img/app/shiba2.jpg'},
  ];

}
```

.css

```
.content {
    padding: 16px;
}

.content > mat-card {
    width: 200px;
}
```

but according to this code the cards are vertical and not in the same row.
and each card has 100 % size of the page.

can someone help me to do this by modifying the code of flex layout

Comment: Did you try to reduce a little fxLayoutGap?

Comment: I try to reduce a little fxLayoutGap fxLayoutGap="5px" without success, the cards are vertical and not in the same row

Comment: Humm. Another thing: Did you try to remove  fxLayout.xs="column" and fxFlex.sm="calc(50%-25px)" to see what happen?

Comment: thanks for the response , I try to remove  fxLayout.xs="column" and fxFlex.sm="calc(50%-25px)" but same thing the cards are vertical and not in the same row

Comment: In my stackblitz it worked (click on open new window to see with the right resolution): https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-v1wvef?file=app/app.component.html